# can I isssue an invoice to a client, on my future business name, before I register as a sole trader with HMRC?

Tags: consulting

I am about to start a consulting project and do not yet have a registered business name. I am thinking of registering as a sole trader.

can I issue a invoices for my services or they can only be issued after i have completed registration with the HMRC ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I invoice my client correctly in the UK?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/590/how-do-i-invoice-my-client-correctly-in-the-uk)

Comment: I wouldn't class that as a duplicate. Although the person states they are not registered, the question is about how to charge clients and invoices, which in my opinion is a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you register as soon as possible. It's easy to register so there's usually no real reason to take a prolonged time to do so.

One would argue that you are not self-employed until you receive your first payment. And there can be good reasons for not registering before you start, such as you got a last minute job where there's no internet connection.

However, if you didn't register for an unusual amount of time, for no reason, they might issue penalties.

**See PMA Business Services [FAQ](http://www.pmabookkeeping.co.uk/index.php/faq-section/)**

> It’s important to let HMRC know that you’re self-employed as soon as
>   possible – even if you already fill in a tax return each year. If you
>   don’t tell them as soon as you begin self employment you may also
>   incur penalties. You can let HMRC know about your new self-employment
>   by registering online for business taxes. You’ll be asked for
>   information about yourself and your business. HMRC will set up tax
>   records for you using the information you provide, for example:

Answer (score 0):

I would think that this would result in a cheque to a company that doesn't have a bank account yet.

Unless paid in cash?

I assume if it's invoiced and paid within the same tax year as you become registered it would not be a problem

Comment: As a sole trader, you can use your personal bank account. However, I wouldn't recommend it. You could, however, use a cheaper alternative personal account for your business, but if your business has a high amount of transactions, you might be breaching the T&C's of your account.